# Where to put code for model entity classes in GWT using GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

Could some explain how to best organize the model entity classes in GWT for use on app engine?

I have been using this ebook as an example to follow http://code.google.com/p/gwt-gae-book/wiki/StoringData, but I am unsure about where to add this code. I do not need help in how to write the classes, I just want to know does this code go in the client or server?

In my application I have one module that handles the UI and that is it so far. My next step is implementing the data functionality features.

I also plan on using twig and appwrench, if possible, in developing my model if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any help in getting this setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am assuming you are new to programming and hence detailed explanation for you:

Everything else except for UI and RPC calls to server will reside in "server" package. Within server side code, you would further like to create modules which interact with each other. Like the layer which receives calls from client and processes them. Another layer which contains core business logic, and next layer which interacts with DB, where your entities/model will reside.

You can look at [example](http://www.vogella.de/articles/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html) for your current problem which separates various layers of code. Only difference being the code is using JSP for it's UI.